# iOS use the volume buttons as input

Tags: iphone, ios5

I've recently downloaded an app that uses the 'Volume -' button to toggle a value, and it uses the 'Volume +' button to start/stop recording of video.  The app is called SloPro, and can be found in the app store.  I thought it wasn't allowed to modify the behaviour of the iPhone's hardware. Any ideas on how this is done?

Comment: I was under the impression that apps like that shouldn't make it into the app store. I wouldn't be surprised if Apple removes the app if they find out what is going on.

Comment: I'd be surprised if they didn't know. The first time you run the app, a message pops up saying this can be done...

Comment: I've added this question to favorites - I'm very curious to see an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the [Audio Session Services References](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioToolbox/Reference/AudioSessionServicesReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007915) for more details, but basically you start an audio session with `AudioSessionInitialize`. Then you make it active with `AudioSessionSetActive`. Then listen for changes in the volume with `AudioSessionAddPropertyListener` where you can pass a callback that has type `AudioSessionPropertyListener`.

Check the following website out for an example:
http://fredandrandall.com/blog/2011/11/18/taking-control-of-the-volume-buttons-on-ios-like-camera/

Comment: I think this is only acceptable in camera apps where it's judiciously used.

Comment: should check the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28193626/cleanest-way-of-capturing-volume-up-down-button-press-on-ios-8 basically you can use https://github.com/jpsim/JPSVolumeButtonHandler