# Launching application on shortcut key in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I want to use shortcut key like long press volume key , or other key sequence to launch my application . Is it really possible with iPhone ?

Answer (score 1):

Answer is simply no.

Apple won't allow you to do this.

They won't allow you to integrate your application with their hardware interface.

Answer (score 0):

No this is not possible for launching the app.

Even within the app apple does not want you to use the hardware buttons, an exception has been made for camera apps.

Here is a thread with details for use within the app:
[Using volume buttons as input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10458438/ios-use-the-volume-buttons-as-input)

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to do this for devices in your control, then you can probably do it by jailbreaking.