# Hardware volume button and Swift

Tags: swift

Looking for a recommended approach to using the hardware volume buttons on iOS devices to control application functions. In this case, the buttons would be used to increase or decrease a qty field in a warehouse-management application.

There have been similar questions about doing this in Objective-C, but I am specifically inquiring about Swift.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS use the volume buttons as input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10458438/ios-use-the-volume-buttons-as-input)

Comment: That question was Objective-C in 2012, I am specifically asking about Swift and do not have any experience with Objective-C

Answer (score 2):

This cannot be done if you want to release your app on the App Store. It will be rejected; the regulations disallow repurposing the hardware buttons for any other function.

As a specific example, some camera apps have been refused for using volume-up as a camera shutter:

> Your application cannot be added to the App Store because it uses
>   iPhone volume buttons in a non-standard way, potentially resulting in
>   user confusion. Changing the behavior of iPhone external hardware
>   buttons is a violation of the iPhone Developer Program License
>   Agreement. Applications must adhere to the iPhone Human Interface
>   Guidelines as outlined in the iPhone Developer Program License
>   Agreement section 3.3.7

http://petapixel.com/2010/08/13/camera-shuttered-from-app-store-for-hidden-banned-feature/

EDIT: since you don't need to work on App Store, I looked for a solution for you and found an older answer you could use. [iOS use the volume buttons as input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10458438/ios-use-the-volume-buttons-as-input)

Comment: While the example was true 4 years ago it got changed like 2 years ago. These days, nearly all camera apps use the volume button(s) to take a photo. New rule is "10.5 Apps that alter the functions of standard switches, such as the Volume Up/Down and Ring/Silent switches, will be rejected". And Camera Shutter on Volume became standard. Probably doesn't make a difference in OPs case though

Comment: App store acceptance isn't top priority. This application will be for internal use only.

Comment: Camera apps started to use the volume button without rejection because Apple's Camera app actually stole the idea from Camera+, suddenly making the "Volume Up = Shutter" the button's "standard function." The rule itself didn't change.